# JRoute don't make a SEF Url from the article link

Tags: sef, joomla-4.x, jroute

When I use Route method to convert a normal url in a SEF url it doesn't work if the article is not a menu item. I don't understand if it's a normal behavior or if I'm doing something wrong. There is my example:

My `$item->link` is "index.php/eng/?view=article&id=29:article-name-1&catid=17".

- If I use `Route::_($item->link)` I obtain an identical url.
- If I use `Route::_(RouteHelper::getArticleRoute($item->slug, $item->catid, $item->language)`, I obtain the same.

They always return "index.php/eng/?view=article&id=29:article-name-1&catid=17" ...but that's not a SEF url.

How can I obtain a SEF url even if the article is not connected to a menu item?

Answer (score 1):

`Route::_()` expects a non-SEF URL as an input.

`index.php/eng/?view=article&id=29:article-name-1&catid=17` is already an SEF URL, which is why `Route::_()` is not modifying it.

A non-SEF URL would be something like:

`index.php?view=article&id=29:article-name-1&catid=17&lang=eng`

Comment: I would prefer a conversion like this: index.php/eng/article/article-name-1
This already happen if an article is connected to a menu item, because the url is changed with something like "/menu-item/article-name-1"

Comment: @Nintendomi I don't think you can have a SEF such as the one you want without a direct link to the article. The Joomla Router requires that.

As for what you get, it also depends on the other menu items on the site, such as maybe having a link to that particular category for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this is now the expected behavior in J4. You need to create a menu item, but it doesn't have to be a menu item for a specific article. Creating a single "List All Categories" menu item is enough.